# Tables basics: One-to-one, many-to-many, one to many

Tags: mysql, database

I want my tables to have different relations between each other, this is my first post and I'm a total dummy.

Each dragon can have multiple eggs, but each egg can have only one owner.

Each egg can have only one adornment(embellishment?) and vice-versa. There cannot be an adornment without an egg.

Dragon can originate from multiple lands, and lands can have multiple dragons, but they can't repeat.

So these are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dragons (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(256),
    colour VARCHAR(256),
    wingspan_in_centimeters INT,
    lands_id INT,
    eggs_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (lands_id) REFERENCES lands (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (eggs_id) REFERENCES eggs (id)
);

CREATE TABLE eggs (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    weight_in_grams INT,
    diameter_in_centimeters INT,
    dragon_id INT,
    adornment_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (dragon_id) REFERENCES dragons (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (adornment_id) REFERENCES eggs_adornments (id)
);

CREATE TABLE eggs_adornments (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    colour VARCHAR(256),
    pattern VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE lands (
    id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(256),
    dragons_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (dragons_id) REFERENCES dragons (id)
);
```

How do I do it?
I'm not sure how foreign keys and references work.

Comment: Neither Eggs nor Lands would appear in the dragons table

Comment: While useful and important, foreign keys and references are, to my mind, something of a red herring. Remember, in a structured query language, it's the query that defines the structure.